# copyObject on Amazon S3 seems very slow

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to move our project storage for our web App to Amazon S3. So far so good but it seems that `copyFolder` is taking much longer then expected and I wonder if I am doing something wrong.

When the user executes a particular command I need to copy two folders on my S3 into a new folder in the same bucket. The first folder contains 4 files and is 45KB and the second folder is 33KB and contains 3 items. On the file system this whole operation takes about 15ms but on S3 it takes at least 1.5 seconds. I did not expect this to be such an order of magnitude in difference on S3 since the files are already on the server but maybe I have a misunderstanding.

Here is the main function I am using to copy the folders:

```
exports.copyFolder = function(oldPath, newPath, callback) {
var _this = this;
console.time("dir");
this.getDirectoryListing(oldPath, function(err, data) {
    console.log("DIR");
    console.timeEnd("dir");
    var params = {
        Bucket: 'bucket-name', 
        Key: newPath,
        CopySource: oldPath
    }
    var filesToCopy = data.length;
    var filesCopied = 0;
    data.forEach(function(fileToCopy) {
        console.time("copy");
        _this.copyFile(fileToCopy.Key, fileToCopy.Key.replace(oldPath, newPath), function() {
            console.log("COPY");
            console.timeEnd("copy");

            filesCopied++;
            if(filesCopied >= filesToCopy && callback) {
                callback();
            }
        });
    });
});    
}
```

Copy File is pretty simple:

```
exports.copyFile = function(oldPath, newPath, callback){
var params = { Bucket: 'bucket-name', Key: newPath, CopySource: 'bucket-path/' + oldPath };
s3.copyObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if(callback)
        callback(err, data);
});
}
```

And `getDirectoryListing` just calls `listObjects` to get all of the files in the source folder. This code is all using Node.js aws-sdk but the calls are to common S3 API calls. Each call to `copyFile` seems to take around 300ms which seems like a lot. Is there anyway to speed this up?

Comment: Is this call happening within AWS (EC2 or Lambda?), or is your NodeJS server hosted somewhere else?

Comment: The node.js server is hosted on EC2 but I am currently working on my dev machine and testing it there.

Comment: I would suggest testing it from EC2 to see if most of the delay is simply network latency. 300ms for sending a request over the internet, waiting for the file to be copied, and waiting for the response to get to you doesn't seem that bad.